# Hide a ListView on a button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, visible

I my ASP.NET 4.5 WebForms app, I have a  . Above it I have a LinkButton to Show/Hide the LinkView. But somw how the ListView's Visible state is not changed only, it's always visible. Here's my code :

```
      <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Visible="true" ID="collapseFloorList" Text="Hide" OnClick="collapseFloorList_Click"></asp:LinkButton>

    <asp:Panel ID="floorPanel" runat="server" >

    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="floorList" 
         ItemType="VincitoreCRMApplication.Models.FloorPattern"
         UpdateMethod="floorList_UpdateItem" DeleteMethod="floorList_DeleteItem"
         SelectMethod="floorList_GetData" DataKeyNames="FloorPatternId" 
         Visible='<%# ShowFloorList %>' >
```

In the Code Behind, I have a Property in PAge named ShowFloorList :

```
    public bool ShowFloorList { get; set; }
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ShowFloorList = true;
        }

    }

    protected void collapseFloorList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("COLLAPSE FLOOR BTN Click Floor List State = " + floorList.Visible + "  BTN TEXT = " + collapseFloorList.Text );

        if (collapseFloorList.Text == "Hide") // Requesting to Hide i.e. Visible to make false
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("INSIDE HIDE");
            ShowFloorList = false;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SHOWFLOOR LIST = " + ShowFloorList);
        }
        else
            ShowFloorList = true;
        /*
        if (ShowFloorList == false)
        {
            collapseFloorList.Text = "Show";
            ShowFloorList = false;
            //floorPanel.Visible = false;
            //floorList.Visible = false;
        }
        {
            collapseFloorList.Text = "Hide";
            ShowFloorList = true;
            floorPanel.Visible = true;
            //floorList.Visible = true;
        } */
    }
```

LOGS :

```
 COLLAPSE FLOOR BTN Click Floor List State = True  BTN TEXT = Hide
 INSIDE HIDE
 SHOWFLOOR LIST = False
```

I tried making the floorLsit directly visible to false, adding it in a panel & making panel visible, and now alos thru property but Nothing works.

Can you tell me why am not able to hide the Listview ??
Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that Link button is actually a link, then !IsPostBack is always false, have you tried changing the LinkButton into asp Button?

EDIT

I've created a sample project for you, open this project NOT as a Project but as a WebSite
[Sample scrollTo and Toggle in jquery](http://wikisend.com/download/958096/WebSite3.zip)

Please don't hesitate if you have questions.

Comment: Yes I tried changing it to asp:Button alos. But same results. Button click is firing ShowFloorList is turned to false, but the visibility of ListView is not turned to false. That is yet visible only.

Comment: Hmm, I think you shouldn't place a Visible='<%# ShowFloorList %>' built in the listview. If you want to control the display of the listview, try doing it straight forward.

1. On your page load inside !IsPostBack, manually set listview.Visible = true
2. On your click button, manually set listview.visible = false

try that, thanks

Comment: Thanks for that. Initially I had done that way only, but that wasn't working so went with panel & finally this way <%# %>. Probably in the initial state, I must be doing something wrong with the if..else condition due to which it didn't work. Or maybe I hadn't added it in if(! IsPostBack). Thanks for your solution.

Comment: One last thing, when I set visible to true, I want the focus on the listview i.e. the page shouldn't be on top, the floorList should be seen directly instead of user going down.In my button click I added                 floorList.Visible = true;                floorList.Focus(); but the focus is not being on the list it is on top only.

Comment: hehe, I don't normally use the .Focus() of asp.net, with the "focusing" feature, what I could best recommend is <script type="javascript"> function floorFocus() { document.getElementById("floorList").focus(); }</script> and then <body onload="floorFocus()" />

Comment: Can you please show code properly and also mention where to add it as I am not used to working with  javascript. And I want focus when the collapsebtn is clicked and listview is made visible. Thanks.

Comment: Please see my post again, please let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

My webforms is a bit rusty but I think you need:

```
Visible="ShowFloorList"
```